# How to pull Django Rest Framework JSON format without array name in AngularJS?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, django, rest, frameworks

I have made a simple DRF page with the following output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "Michel", 
        "city": "Florida", 
        "country": "United States"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 2, 
        "name": "Hasan", 
        "city": "London", 
        "country": "United Kingdom"
    }
]
```

I have the following code in HTML:

```
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in info">
            {{ x.name + ', ' + x.country }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have the following in a .js file:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("localhost:8000/index/info/")
    .success(function(response) {
        $scope.info = response[array name was supposed to go here];
});
```

The tutorial that I am following is [this](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp), which has the whole data in a an array with an array name. They used the name after `response`, see the .js file code. My question is, how can I give a name to my array, or call this array without a name?

Comment: Go through this https://thinkster.io/django-angularjs-tutorial/

Comment: http://blog.kevinastone.com/getting-started-with-django-rest-framework-and-angularjs.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27282360/django-and-angularjs-sending-query-json-data-to-angular

Comment: I have gone through these links guys. I think if I just figure my code out I can be confident to follow those tutorials. I feel that they are a bit too advanced for me.

Comment: It's unclear for me what you're trying to accomplish.
Could you add some pseudo-code of the desired state?

Comment: I have not worked on this for a long time.

Will get back to you later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $scope.projects = [];
$http.get('/api/projects/').success(function(data) {
    $scope.projects = data;
    console.log($scope.projects);

});
```

Source:
[Django and AngularJS - Sending query JSON data to Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27282360/django-and-angularjs-sending-query-json-data-to-angular)

Comment: Tried this. The page tries loading for a long time and then it shows The webpage is not available. Same problem as before.

Comment: Made a mistake with the URL. Now it just shows `{{ x.name + ', ' + x.country }}`. :-/